# Расчет ширины неравных блоков при помощи calc

Tags: css

Для верстки секции, разделенной на равное количество колонок c отступом, заданном переменной я использовал следующий расчет ширины

```
:root { 
--gap: 30px; 
}
.column {
width: calc((100% - (var(--gap))) / 4);
}
```

Сейчас мне нужно сверстать секцию, разбитую на два неравных блока, один из которых занимает одну колонку, а другой - три, отступы между блоками и колонками равные и так же находятся в переменной . Как это можно сделать при помощи  calc?